# mysql IO read rate is very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, io, innodb

I have a very simple query

```
select * from ap_statistic
```

running in my servers. The servers have the same hardware and software configuration (CPU 8 core, mem :32G, OS: redhat 5.5, mysql version: 5.1 ) and run the same applications.

In server A, the row number of the table `ap_statistic` is about 22,512,379, in server B, the row number of the table is 41,438,751. Of course the query running on server A is faster than server B, but what is strange is the query on server B is extreme slow, it takes more than 1 hours where in server A it just takes 10 minutes.

I use some tool to monitor system status and find that when the query is running in server A, system IO read speed is about 20~30M/s, but in server B it's 2~3M/s. I've tried to clean linux cache and restart mysql server, all is the same result. And I tried to restored DB from server B to server A, so the query in Server A is very very slow and io read speed is very slow. I want to know why this happens?

Comment: What is the structure of the DBs and what is the query?

Comment: Are you using the same MySQL storage engine on both systems?

Comment: Have you tried adding `EXPLAIN` to the queries - maybe - as a guess the engine estimates  are out of date on one of the servers - be interested in the answer to this

Comment: Any differences in hdd configuration?  Compare output from hdparm to see if something is set differently on drives on different servers.  Even a loose sata/sas cable could cause a speed issue like this.

Comment: Also, what tool are you using to measure system io?

Comment: I's post lot of monitor tool output in my another post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838162/select-from-statement-execute-very-slowly-innodb-io-read-speed-is-low

Comment: Adrian Cornish, I use explain command in 2 servers, the same result:

  id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE ap_statistic ALL \N \N \N \N 44510287

Comment: Try to repair the slow table and see if it makes a difference if you order by PK.

Comment: it's very strange, I fill another table with 11200000 rows, then use select * from to query this table, it's quit fast, and I can see that system IO read rate is about 10M~20M/s

Comment: I've resolve this question, it's because table fragments. after my optimizing the table, the table space shrinks from 18G to 12G and IO read rate is about 20~30M/s

Comment: @MattSuo Can you please post `SHOW CREATE TABLE ap_statistic`?